# Inductor position in low side buck converter

Tags: buck, emc, led-driver, constant-current

I am designing a PCB to control an RGBW-LED. To provide a regualted current for each color I am using the LM3407 buck converter from TI. The buck converter is powered with 12V and is configured to provide 350mA load current.

[LM3407 Website](https://www.ti.com/product/LM3407) 
[LM3407 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3407.pdf)

The datasheet of the LM3407 recommends the following schematic:

[image]

I transformed this schematic to the following pcb:

[image]

But now I am wondering if the position of the inductor can be changed to this:

[image]

I transformed this schematic to the following pcb:

[image]

**Are there any advantages and disadvantages depending on where the inductor is placed? (The aspect of EMC is particularly interesting to me)**

I am using a 4-Layer FR4 PCB using the following stackup:

[image]

Comment: General rule is to keep inductor traces as short as possible (loop as small as possible). And watch out for sensitive signals going close to inductor.

Comment: you'd want to fatten up the tracks in the boost loop to minimise inductance.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!  Good advice in the comments - there is a layout recommendation in the data sheet.

[image]

With the recommended schematic (your first figure above), when the switch is "on," the current in the inductor starts to rise as current flows through the LED and through the switch.  When the switch is open, the voltage on L1 pin 1 will rise until D1 turns on, and the inductor current drops until the switch turns back on.  D2 pin 1 is always at 12 volts, and D2 pin 2 could theoretically go as low as ground if the switch stayed on long enough, but it is always below 12 volts.  You would have the current as shown in the data sheet below.

[image]

[image]

If you put the inductor on the opposite side as in your third figure above, D2 pin 2 gets pulled to ground when the switch is on, and the inductor starts to charge up as before.  But when the switch is off, the D2 pin 2 must now reach a voltage greater than 12 volts to turn on D1, and D2 pin 1 must increase to a voltage large enough to  keep current flowing in both diodes.  So you are basically switching D2 pin 2 between 12 volts and ground, and both sides of D2 and C1 follow, jumping 12 volts every time you switch, with the attendant spiking and ringing.  The voltage on L1 pin 1 is some voltage above 12 volts, high enough to power D2 when the switch is "off," and jumps to near the same voltage above ground when the switch is "on."

So this is not a recommended approach, although from a strictly theoretical standpoint I think you are on solid ground.